VUE Element is missing end tag
I have the following in Vue3 where I'm trying to put items into a bootstrap row and each row should contain 6 items. However, VueJS doesn't like me doing this! It complains that my first <b-row> contains a missing closing tag (which it does by design!) :

[plugin:vite:vue] Element is missing end tag.

How would I need to restructure this to play ball nicely in VUE?
<main role="main" class="container-fluid">
    <div class="container">
        <template v-for="(item, index) in items">
            <template v-if="index == 0 || index % 6 == 0">
                <b-row>
            </template>
                <b-col>
                {{ item.name }}
                </b-col>
            <template v-if="(index != 0 && index % 6 == 0) || index == items.length">
                </b-row>
            </template>
        </template>
    </div>
</main>


It doesn't work like that, in Vue.js you cannot break such html tags.. First you have to break the array into pieces and then run them in a v-for:
<script setup>
const items = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13];

const chunkArray = (arr, size) => arr.reduce((acc, _, index) => {
    if (index % size === 0) {
        acc.push(arr.slice(index, index + size));
    }
    return acc;
}, []);


const chankItems = chunkArray(items, 6);
</script>

<template>
<main>
  <div v-for="items in chankItems">
    <span v-for="el in items">
      {{ el }};
    </span>
  </div>
</main>
</template>

Vue SFC Playground

@kissu please explain why you are editing my answer without making any changes? Because this is not the first time.

Prefer using the html language preset for VueJS code, it is more accurate in terms of highlighting (maybe one day SO will implement something more specific haha). Nothing else other than better reading here so far. Feel free to keep the rollback if you do not like it, sir.

OK. Understand. It just doesn't do any good, that's why I asked.

Most of the time it's better but maybe wasn't all too relevant here, just a habit that I picked over the months haha.

What you're trying to do is make rows 6 items by 6 items from your original array. To do that you can use an algorithm that is usually named chunks.
What it does is take an array of items as input, as well as a maximum number of items per chunk (let's call it n), and returns an array of arrays of items whose length is n except the last one which has the constraint length <= n as you might not be able to split your array evenly.
Like this:
// Some JS file
export const function chunks(arr, maxItemsPerChunk) {
  let currChunk = [];
  const chunksArr = arr.reduce((chunks, item, i) => {
    if (i !== 0 && i % maxItemsPerChunk === 0) {
      // The current chunk has reached its limit
      // therefore we push it into the results
      // and update the new current chunk to contain the current item
      chunks.push(currChunk);
      currChunk = [item];
    } else {
      // The current chunk hasn't reached its limit
      // just yet, so we push the item into it
      currChunk.push(item);
    }

    return chunks;
  }, []);

  if (currChunk.length) {
    // If there are leftovers, that means the
    // number of items in the array was not
    // divisible by maxItemsPerChunk.
    // Thus we push the last chunk whose length
    // is strictly less than maxItemsPerChunk
    chunksArr.push(currChunk);
  }

  return chunksArr;
}

And use it in your component like this:
<!-- The vue component -->
<script setup>
import { chunks } from "...";
const items = /* [...] */;

const chunkedItems = computed(() => chunks(items, 6));
</script>

<template>
<main role="main" class="container-fluid">
    <div class="container">
        <!-- TODO: Find a better key for the chunks -->
        <b-row v-for="(chunk, index) in chunks" :key="index">
            <!-- TODO: Find a better key for the items -->
            <b-col v-for="(item, index) in chunk" :key="index">
                {{ item.name }}
            </b-col>
        </b-row>
    </div>
</main>
</template>


You can restructure it to work this way instead:
<template>
  <main role="main" class="container-fluid">
    <div class="container">
      <template v-for="(row, rowIndex) in itemRows" :key="rowIndex">
        <b-row>
          <template v-for="(item, itemIndex) in row" :key="itemIndex">
            <b-col>
              {{ item.name }}
            </b-col>
          </template>
        </b-row>
      </template>
    </div>
  </main>
</template>

<script setup>
const items = ref([
  {
    name: "Hello",
  },
// add as many more elements as you'd like
]);

const itemRows = computed(() => {
  const rows = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < this.items.length; i += 6) {
    rows.push(this.items.slice(i, i + 6));
  }
  return rows;
});
</script>

Basically use the computed property itemRows to split the items array into chunks of 6.
This restructure ensures that each  contains exactly 6  elements, and any remaining items (if the total number of items isn't a multiple of 6) will be placed in the last row.
Here's my result:

I hope this helps. If you have any other questions, let me know.
